# ONVIF Python tool usage

Tags: python, onvif

ONVIF tool:

https://github.com/quatanium/python-onvif

I've installed correctly (here below the installation diagnostic) but I do not understand howto proceed from the step "Getting Started" on.
What the entry "from onvif import ONVIFCamera" refers to?

I hope to receive a clue!

Many thanks and best regards, Sergio

```
sudo python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to onvif.egg-info/requires.txt
writing onvif.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to onvif.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to onvif.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to onvif.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'onvif.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'README.'
writing manifest file 'onvif.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif
copying build/lib.linux-armv6l-2.7/onvif/cli.py -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif
copying build/lib.linux-armv6l-2.7/onvif/client.py -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif
copying build/lib.linux-armv6l-2.7/onvif/exceptions.py -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif
copying build/lib.linux-armv6l-2.7/onvif/definition.py -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif
copying build/lib.linux-armv6l-2.7/onvif/version.txt -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif
copying build/lib.linux-armv6l-2.7/onvif/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif/cli.py to cli.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif/client.py to client.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif/exceptions.py to exceptions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif/definition.py to definition.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onvif/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
installing package data to build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg
running install_data
creating build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/remotediscovery.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/rw-2.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/accesscontrol.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/addressing -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/doorcontrol.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/bf-2.xsd -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/receiver.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/t-1.xsd -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/recording.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/bw-2.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/ws-discovery.xsd -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/xmlmime -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/b-2.xsd -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/analyticsdevice.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/ptz.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/actionengine.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/xml.xsd -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/r-2.xsd -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/ws-addr.xsd -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/advancedsecurity.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/replay.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/onvif.xsd -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/include -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/search.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/media.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/imaging.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/envelope -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/events.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/deviceio.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/analytics.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/types.xsd -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
copying wsdl/display.wsdl -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/wsdl
creating build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
copying onvif.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
copying onvif.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
copying onvif.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
copying onvif.egg-info/entry_points.txt -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
copying onvif.egg-info/not-zip-safe -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
copying onvif.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
copying onvif.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
creating 'dist/onvif-0.2.0-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing onvif-0.2.0-py2.7.egg
removing '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/onvif-0.2.0-py2.7.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/onvif-0.2.0-py2.7.egg
Extracting onvif-0.2.0-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
onvif 0.2.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing onvif-cli script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/onvif-0.2.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for onvif==0.2.0
Searching for suds-passworddigest==0.1.2
Best match: suds-passworddigest 0.1.2
Processing suds_passworddigest-0.1.2-py2.7.egg
suds-passworddigest 0.1.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds_passworddigest-0.1.2-py2.7.egg
Searching for suds==0.4
Best match: suds 0.4
Processing suds-0.4-py2.7.egg
suds 0.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg
Finished processing dependencies for onvif==0.2.0
```

Comment: It's *importing* the `ONVIFCamera` class *from* the `onvif` module. If you want to use a Python tool you should probably first gain basic familiarity with Python code and syntax; see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Thank you to have replied and thank you to have addressed my doubt. I'll be back asap with a better knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

`from onvif import ONVIFCamera` means it will import the `ONVIFCamera` class definition from the `onvif` module (in which you have installed in the previous step). You could find the definition of ONVIFCamera class in this [file](https://github.com/quatanium/python-onvif/blob/master/onvif/client.py)

Comment: Thank you Andreas!
I was able to complete the first step of testing via connection to the camera.
Mean while I'm checking on camera side, I'd like to ask the community if the python-onvif ONVIF client has implemented 'profile G'. I need to access the file-record stored in the SD card.
thx&brgrds, s.

Comment: @SergioAiello ask that question on the github project you mentioned in your quesiton https://github.com/quatanium/python-onvif